# Checking where $\log_e(z^5+1)$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, logarithms

Consider the function $f: D \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(z) = \log_e(z^5+1)$. Obviously, to check that it is analytic we can let $z = x+iy$ and the verify where the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied. This involves the expansion of $(x+iy)^5$ however, and I don't think anyone wants to do that.

Is there a faster method?

Comment: It's odd that you've chosen to write $\log_e$ rather than $\ln$

Comment: Another option is to factor $z^5 + 1$ and then split up the log of a product

Comment: Alternatively, if you've already proven something like "the composition of analytic functions is itself analytic", then you don't have to mess around with the Cauchy Riemann equations here.

Comment: This question cannot be answered because $D$ is undefined.